# Force Quirks mode with Doctype

Tags: html, doctype

I have a page which needs to be rendered in Quirks mode for the page to be loaded properly. The problem is that the page uses valid XHTML and thus has a doctype. This forces the page to render in Standards mode in all browsers. Is there any workaround/hack that can force Quirks mode eventhough I have a doctype?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to address the reason behind requiring quirksmode. Can you give us a clue what it is?

Comment: Have a look at the page here: http://ameer1234567890.cu.cc/quick-dial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/ for changing the `DOCTYPE` to **Almost Standards mode** or **Quirks mode**. Excerpts below. (Assumes a `Content-Type` of `text/html`.)

**Almost Standards mode:**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

> This gives you the Almost Standards mode. Please note that your
>   layouts based on sliced images in tables are likely to break if you
>   later move to HTML5 (and, hence, the full Standards mode), so it’s
>   better to make your designs Standards mode-compatible right now.

**Quirks mode:**

> **No doctype.**
>
> Please don’t do this. Willfully designing for the Quirks mode will
>   come and haunt you, your coworkers or your successors in the future.

**XHTML doctype:**

> I am not recommending any of the XHTML doctypes, because [serving XHTML
>   as `text/html` is considered harmful](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml). If you choose to use an XHTML
>   doctype anyway, please note that the XML declaration makes IE 6 (but
>   not IE 7!) trigger the Quirks mode.

Answer (score 6):

I also have a page that must live in the 90s along with all the memory leaks that come with IE in quirks mode, this is the DOCTYPE we use.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
```

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the doctype?

Comment: Then, my page does not validate!

Comment: Nor should it, if it requires a non-standard renderer.

Comment: @Ameer, so ... you want it to validate as xhtml, but not render as xhtml ... pretty weird requirement if you ask me ..

Comment: The problem is that the page does't load properly (for some unknown reason) with doctype, eventhough it is valid XHTML and CSS.